# TableView starts in the wrong position initially

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

This issue has come about as I update an app from iOS 7 to iOS 8. My tableview starts in the wrong position initially. Once you touch it or scroll it. The tableview scrolls into the correct position and works as intended.

The table view is embedded within a UIPageViewController.

```
UITableView *tableView = (id) [self.view viewWithTag:5];
[tableView registerClass:[BroadcastCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellBroadcastTableIdentifier];
[tableView registerClass:[BroadcastHeaderCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellBroadcastHeaderTableIdentifier];
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 64.0f)];
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 0.0f)];
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.opaque = NO;
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Screenshot can be found - https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Byh_5eIIQAA06ok.png:large

Comment: Issue caused by having 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' checked on the storyboard for the parent view controller which contained the UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. After much effort I found out that in the previous view I was using

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title-bar-bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I changed it to

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title-bar-bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and the problem was solved.

Comment: My navigation doesn't have an image for the background. Do you know why it solved it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know. But it seems it has something to do with uinavigationbar appearence method in iOS8. May be if I get more details of your code i might know.

Comment: Your comment about the previous view helped direct where I should be checking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select your View Controller and Deselect property 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' on the storyboard (under View Controller section).

OR

Add following lines

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;